# Random Walk and strong law

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, markov-chains, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

I want to prove that a Random Walk in 1 dimension is transient when $p\neq\frac{1}{2}$ but i want to prove it by the strong law of large numbers, so i have this:
Define a random variable $$X_i = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if you go to the right }\\
    -1 & \quad \text{if you go to the left}
  \end{array} \right.$$ 
With probabilities $P(X_i=1)=p \quad, P(X_i=-1)=1-p$, where each $X_i$ is independent with the same distribution. Now by the strong law of large numbers $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}\to E[X_i] \quad as \quad n\to \infty $$
I want to prove that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i=\infty$ when $p>\frac12$ i.e the position or state at time n is $\infty$, it means that the walk never returns to any state, hence the random walk is transient. But i don't know how to prove the last limit, and i don't understand my teacher's hint of use the strong law because i think is not necessary. Hope you help me.

Comment: Since $p > \frac{1}{2}$, we have $\mathbb{E}[X_1] > 0$ and the strong law of large numbers states that the sample average converges almost surely towards the expected value. This indicates that $\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ tends to $+\infty$. See for example [Section 31](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/L/McRw/mcrw.pdf) or [Slide 21](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~joye/quawagtalks/Guillotin.pdf)